# New open xml word doc hyperlinks look like normal text

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk

I'm generating a MS Word document using the OpenXML SDK.  I can successfully create a new document and insert hyperlinks.  The problem is when opened in MS Word 2010, the link looks like normal text.  After examining the file /word/styles.xml I've found it doesn't contain the "Hyperlink" style.  How can I programmatically access or create this classic style?

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25056927/unable-to-use-existing-paragraph-styles-in-open-xml/25058393#25058393). They styles in that question / answer are different but the concept is the same.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @petelids.  I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Paragraph res = new Paragraph(
new Hyperlink(new ProofError() { Type = ProofingErrorValues.GrammarStart },
                             new Run(
                                 new RunProperties(
                                 new RunStyle() { Val = "Hyperlink" }
                                 ),
                                 new Text("Text")
                             )
                             { RsidRunProperties = uniqueId},
                             new ProofError() { Type = ProofingErrorValues.GrammarEnd }
                             )
                         {
                             Id = relationid,
                             History = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OnOffValue(true)
                         }
)
```

Comment: Could you document your snippet? :)