# Creating an Office Open XML document with mutliple styles

Tags: c#, openxml, docx, openxml-sdk

I am having issues with Office Open XML. I have been able to take some code off the internet and make a document with `Hello World` and also add a heading to the document, however, other than that, I am having no success.

We are moving OOXML since `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` takes too long for the clients and in my experience not a lot of people put Office in a server environment.

Basically, I create an object array with 7 Properties per object.

```
public class BusinessRule
{
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    public string PATH { get; set; }
    public string LEVEL { get; set; }
    public string DESCRIPTION { get; set; }
    public string[] ROUTINGRULES { get; set; }
    public string[] FILENAMINGRULES { get; set; }
    public string[] ADDITIONALBUSINESSMETADATA { get; set; }
}
```

My current code strips through some files and populates this object array called `businessRules`.

Now that I have all the rules, I need to spit them out into a `.docx`. The created document needs to have 6 styles; Heading 1, Heading 2, Heading 3, etc...

The code below is my attempt to create the styles that I need before I start writing the different items to the document. Some things are commented out in an attempt to make it work. It also has some repeated code to try and get around some errors. I know this is some really bad code so I apologise to your eyes and brains in advance.

```
    //return styles
    private Style[] getStyle()
    {
        List<Style> styles = new List<Style>();

        //initialise objects
        RunProperties rPrH1 = new RunProperties();
        RunProperties rPrH2 = new RunProperties();
        RunProperties rPrH3 = new RunProperties();
        RunProperties rPrH4 = new RunProperties();
        RunProperties rPrH5 = new RunProperties();
        RunProperties rPrH6 = new RunProperties();
        RunProperties rPrN = new RunProperties();




        Color[] color = new Color[3];
        color[0] = new Color();
        color[0].Val = "4F81BD";
        color[1] = new Color();
        color[1].Val = "144E85";
        color[2] = new Color();
        color[2].Val = "000000";

        RunFonts rFont = new RunFonts();
        rFont.Ascii = "Calibri Light"; // the font is Arial
        rPrH1.Append(rFont);
        rFont = new RunFonts();
        rFont.Ascii = "Calibri Light"; // the font is Arial
        rPrH2.Append(rFont);
        rFont = new RunFonts();
        rFont.Ascii = "Calibri Light"; // the font is Arial
        rPrH3.Append(rFont);
        rFont = new RunFonts();
        rFont.Ascii = "Calibri Light"; // the font is Arial
        rPrH4.Append(rFont);
        rFont = new RunFonts();
        rFont.Ascii = "Calibri Light"; // the font is Arial
        rPrH5.Append(rFont);
        rFont = new RunFonts();
        rFont.Ascii = "Calibri Light"; // the font is Arial
        rPrH6.Append(rFont);
        rFont = new RunFonts();
        rFont.Ascii = "Calibri Light"; // the font is Arial
        rPrN.Append(rFont);

        //Add heading 1
        //4F81BD -  Calibri Light - 16
        //creation of a style
        Style H1 = new Style();
        H1.StyleId = "Heading1"; //this is the ID of the style
        H1.Append(new Name() { Val = "Heading 1" }); //this is name                                 
                                                     // our style based on Normal style
        H1.Append(new BasedOn() { Val = "Heading1" });
        // the next paragraph is Normal type
        H1.Append(new NextParagraphStyle() { Val = "Heading 5" });
        //run properties
        //rPrH1.Append(color[0]);
        //rPr.Append(new Bold()); // it is Bold
        rPrH1.Append(new FontSize() { Val = "16" }); //font size (in 1/72 of an inch)
        H1.Append(rPrH1);

        //Add heading 2
        //4F81BD -  Calibri Light - 13
        Style H2 = new Style();
        H2.StyleId = "Heading2"; //this is the ID of the style
        H2.Append(new Name() { Val = "Heading 2" }); //this is name                                 
                                                     // our style based on Normal style
        H2.Append(new BasedOn() { Val = "Heading2" });
        // the next paragraph is Normal type
        H2.Append(new NextParagraphStyle() { Val = "Heading 5" });
        //run properties
        rPrH2.Append(color[0]);
        rPrH2.Append(new FontSize() { Val = "13" }); //font size (in 1/72 of an inch)
        H2.Append(rPrH2);

        //Add heading 3
        //144E85 -  Calibri Light - 12
        Style H3 = new Style();
        H3.StyleId = "Heading3"; //this is the ID of the style
        H3.Append(new Name() { Val = "Heading 3" }); //this is name                                 
                                                     // our style based on Normal style
        H3.Append(new BasedOn() { Val = "Heading3" });
        // the next paragraph is Normal type
        H3.Append(new NextParagraphStyle() { Val = "Heading 5" });
        //run properties
        rPrH3.Append(color[1]);
        rPrH3.Append(new FontSize() { Val = "12" }); //font size (in 1/72 of an inch)
        H3.Append(rPrH3);

        //Add heading 4
        //144E85 -  Calibri Light - 11
        Style H4 = new Style();
        H4.StyleId = "Heading4"; //this is the ID of the style
        H4.Append(new Name() { Val = "Heading 4" }); //this is name                                 
                                                     // our style based on Normal style
        H4.Append(new BasedOn() { Val = "Heading4" });
        // the next paragraph is Normal type
        H4.Append(new NextParagraphStyle() { Val = "Heading 5" });
        //run properties
        rPrH4.Append(color[1]);
        rPrH4.Append(new FontSize() { Val = "11" }); //font size (in 1/72 of an inch)
        H4.Append(rPrH4);

        //Add heading 5
        //4F81BD -  Calibri Light - 11
        Style H5 = new Style();
        H5.StyleId = "Heading5"; //this is the ID of the style
        H5.Append(new Name() { Val = "Heading 5" }); //this is name                                 
                                                     // our style based on Normal style
        H5.Append(new BasedOn() { Val = "Heading5" });
        // the next paragraph is Normal type
        //H5.Append(new NextParagraphStyle() { Val = "Normal" });
        //run properties
        rPrH5.Append(color[0]);
        rPrH5.Append(new FontSize() { Val = "11" }); //font size (in 1/72 of an inch)
        H5.Append(rPrH5);

        //Add heading 6
        //144E85 -  Calibri Light - 11
        Style H6 = new Style();
        H6.StyleId = "Heading6"; //this is the ID of the style
        H6.Append(new Name() { Val = "Heading 6" }); //this is name                                 
                                                     // our style based on Normal style
        H6.Append(new BasedOn() { Val = "Heading6" });
        // the next paragraph is Normal type
        //H6.Append(new NextParagraphStyle() { Val = "Normal" });
        //run properties
        rPrH6.Append(color[1]);
        rPrH6.Append(new FontSize() { Val = "11" }); //font size (in 1/72 of an inch)
        H6.Append(rPrH6);

        //Add normal
        //000000 -  Calibri Light - 11
        Style N = new Style();
        H6.StyleId = "Normal"; //this is the ID of the style
        H6.Append(new Name() { Val = "Normal" }); //this is name                                 
                                                  // our style based on Normal style
        H6.Append(new BasedOn() { Val = "Normal" });
        //run properties
        rPrN.Append(color[2]);
        rPrN.Append(new FontSize() { Val = "11" }); //font size (in 1/72 of an inch)
        N.Append(rPrN);

        return styles.ToArray();
    }
```

If someone even has some demo code that uses 3 styles I might be able to get my head around it a bit more.

Cheers,
JohZant

Comment: I have an example with 3 styles in my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25056927/unable-to-use-existing-paragraph-styles-in-open-xml/25058393#25058393) - if that helps I'll try to find time to write up an answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I worked this out ages ago, but I forgot about this question. OOPS!

I will be honest, I did cheat. Like, a lot. But I'm not trying to reinvent the wheel here.

The Open XML SDK Tool (https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=30425) allowed me to upload a docx that I created manually with all the styles I needed, and then it gave me the C# to use to create the document programmatically.

[Open XML SDK Tool on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/Open-XML-SDK/releases/tag/v2.5)

Comment: More specifically: this feature is available in Open XML SDK Productivity Tools. Just open the document you are interested in and "Reflect code".