# openxml use predefined styles in a blank word

Tags: c#, styles, openxml

I want to apply some styles that are predefined in word. My code is as follows, but the style "Heading1" doesn't work.

```
WordprocessingDocument wordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(document, true);
Body body = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;

Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
ParagraphProperties ppr = new ParagraphProperties();
ParagraphStyleId stid = new ParagraphStyleId() { Val = "Heading1" };
ppr.Append(stid);
p.Append(ppr);
```

Comment: Did you include the style definitions in the document?  Create a blank Word doc (in Word) and save it.  Then open the document up in the OpenXml productivity tool and reflect the code.  You'll see _**lots**_ of styles defined in the document.  You need to create the same kind of style section with the style(s) you need to be able to use them in your document.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to use existing paragraph styles in Open Xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25056927/unable-to-use-existing-paragraph-styles-in-open-xml)